# customizing action bar sherlock

Tags: android

I have implemented Action bar Sherlock with theme.sherlock. The action bar has navigation tab. I have used styles for customizing the action bar. The style xml is shown below

```
 <resources>
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
<item name= "actionBarStyle">@style/ActionStyle</item>
<item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
</style>
<style name= "ActionStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionstyle</item>
   <item name="background">@drawable/actionstyle</item>
  </style>
<style name="MyTabTextStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText" >
<item name="android:textColor">#0EBFE9</item>
<item name ="android:textStyle">bold</item>
<item name= "android:textSize">14dp</item>
</style>
 </resources>
```

the drawable action style

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Bottom Line -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Color of your action bar -->
<item android:bottom="2dip">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

I need to 
 remove the divider between action bar and navigation tab 
 show blue divider  below the navigation tab

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is setting the `background` property of your xml. You can set the "color" **transparent** to remove it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Bottom Line -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Color of your action bar -->
    <item android:bottom="2dip">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/action_bar_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Afterwards apply it in your theme:

```
<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
</style>
```