# In android while creating a customized theme for my application , I am unable to access android :actionbarstyle?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, themes

This is the XML i have. I cannot access actionbarstyle

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->`[<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
   <item name="android:textColor">#ffa500</item>

   <item name="android:actionbarstyle"
</style>
```

It does not recognize my actionbarstyle.when i try to use content assist it does not show up the actionbarstyle option

i have my manifest file

CAN ANYONE PLEASE EXPLAIN HOW TO CUSTOMIZE ACTION BAR PROPERTY FOR MY APPLICATION?

A small question . What is the difference between ACTIONBAR AND ACTIONBARSHERLOCK ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is `Actionbar` is a native android widget while 'ActionbarSherlok' is a widget that belong to a thrid party library with the same name. see [`Styling the Action Bar`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) to see how to customize android Actionbar and refer this post to see how to customize Sherlock Actionbar [customizing action bar sherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831338/customizing-action-bar-sherlock)